# Invalid iso code stored in /content/myapp/uk/en: en_uk

Tags: aem

I am new to Adobe CQ, when i am opening a page from '/content'

> GET /content/myapp/uk/en.html HTTP/1.1]
>   com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageImpl Invalid iso code stored in
>   /content/myapp/uk/en: en_uk

is appearing in my logs, how to resolve this ?

Comment: can you provide the node and jcr:content properties of your `/content/myapp/uk/en` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue by adding a `jcr:language` property in the `/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content` node as shown in the below image, which produces me the below error.

> 27.01.2017 14:38:46.640 *WARN* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1485549526613] GET /content/geometrixx/en.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.PageImpl Invalid iso code stored in /content/geometrixx/en: en_UK
>   27.01.2017 14:38:48.337 *WARN* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1485549528325] GET /etc/clientcontext/default/content/jcr:content/stores.init.js HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.LanguageManagerImpl Invalid iso code stored in /content/geometrixx/en: en_UK

you have to use the correct iso code i.e. `en_GB` as per the [standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Naming_and_code_construction).

and also have a look at the [Page](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/v5_1/cq-wcm-javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#getLanguage(boolean)), [PageImpl](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/v5_1/cq-wcm-javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/core/impl/PageImpl.html) `getLanguage()` method for more understanding

[image: jcr:language]

After adding the correct code `en_GB` i can see proper logs without any `*WARN*` when i access the page

> 27.01.2017 14:51:44.312 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1485550304292] GET /content/geometrixx/en.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.JcrResourceBundle Finding all dictionaries for 'en_GB' (basename: ) ...
>   27.01.2017 14:51:44.343 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1485550304292] GET /content/geometrixx/en.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.JcrResourceBundle Finished loading 0 entries for 'en_GB' (basename: ) in 31ms
>   27.01.2017 14:51:44.345 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1485550304292] GET /content/geometrixx/en.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.i18n Service [5690, [java.util.ResourceBundle]] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
>   27.01.2017 14:51:44.345 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1485550304292] GET /content/geometrixx/en.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.JcrResourceBundleProvider Currently loaded dictionaries across all locales: [/libs/foundation/components/mobilefooter/i18n/en, /libs/cq/searchpromote/components/pagination/i18n/en, /libs/social/subscriptions/components/hbs/subscriptions/i18n/en, /libs/foundation/components/search/i18n/en, /libs/social/commons/components/hbs/comments/i18n/en, /libs/commerce/components/search/i18n/en]

~Hope it helps

Comment: @VAr-Thanks for response and it is working as you said.