# Can the "jcr:language" property be configured automatically on page creation?

Tags: aem

How is the `jcr:language` property is being configured in the below site structure, for example, on the node (`/content/myapp/uk/en/jcr:content`)?

```js
{
    "content": {
        "myapp": {
            "jcr:content" {
                "us": {
                    "jcr:mixinTypes": "rep:AccessControllable",
                    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Page"
                },
                "de": {
                    "jcr:mixinTypes": "rep:AccessControllable",
                    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Page"
                },
                "fr": {
                    "jcr:mixinTypes": "rep:AccessControllable",
                    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Page"
                },
                "uk": {
                    "jcr:mixinTypes": "rep:AccessControllable",
                    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Page",
                    "jcr:content": {},
                    "en": {
                        "jcr:content": {},
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This question is related to [Invalid iso code stored in /content/myapp/uk/en: en_uk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887845/invalid-iso-code-stored-in-content-myapp-uk-en-en-uk). I can remove the warnings mentioned in that question by changing the `jcr:language` value to `en_GB` manually in the page, the warnings are gone.

But I want to configure it in such a way that the correct `jcr:language` property should be automatically set to `en_GB`, while creating the language node itself (i.e `en`). Is this possible?

Comment: Edited your question for readability — if I've misread your intent, please edit over the top again, or feel free to roll back my change

Comment: @anotherdave - Appreciate the Edit ! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@raju muddana **i would like to know your use case for automatically creating the jcr:language property**.

Generally this language property is left over to content authors after your project implementation. in AEM any number of pages will be created with one template wich can be used for multi languages content authoring. Generally we can segregate this with content structures like an example shown in geometrix demo site (example: /content/geometrixx/en, /content/geometrixx/fr, etc.). once the content structure has been established content-authors can set this language property accordingly.

In addition to @i.net answer, just showing you that on any page in AEM by default you can add the language by using **Page Properties** `Advanced` Tab `Language` property. until unless if you don't customize your page properties.

Classic UI:
[image: classic UI]
Touch UI:
[image: Touch UI]

Jcr:language Property 
[image: jcr-language]

Comment: @ VAr - Thanks gain. Nice Explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the jcr:language to en_GB on /content/myapp/jcr:content/uk/jcr:content node. This will ensure that any pages below this node that don't have the jcr:language defined will pick this property from the parent node.